# Adding a key and value to already existing session

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

I try to add a key and a value in a already existing session with laravel and this goes fine but the key is not as I pass with the Session function

```
public function selectCar() {

    $reservation['car'] = Input::get('id'); 

    if (Session::has('car')) {
        Session::forget('car');
    }

    if (Input::has('id'))
    {
        Session::push('reserveringen', $reservation['car']);
    }

    $data = Session::all();
    return Redirect::back()->with('success', 'Auto gekozen')->with('sessie', $data);

}
```

The output is

```
[reserveringen] => Array
            (
                [pickupdate] => 'date'
                [pickuptime] => 'time'
                [returndate] => 'date'
                [returntime] => 'time'
                [0] => 37
            )
```

But It shows 0 instead of 'car' The next thing is that if the session already contains car I want the old one to delete and be replace by the new one. Can someone give me an example of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not passing the array key, so this is a way to pass it:

```
if (Input::has('id'))
{
    Session::push('reserveringen', array('car' => $reservation['car']));
}
```

But it will push an new array to that array, not your 'car' key.

So, you might need to do this to put your 'car' key correctly:

```
$reserveringen = Session::get('reserveringen');

$reserveringen['car'] = $reservation['car'];

Session::put('reserveringen', $reserveringen);
```